# What is a good and stable way to implement graphs and trees using STL in C++?

Tags: c++, graph, stl, tree, implementation

As an alternative to the classic pointer representations of binary trees and adjacency list, what would be a good way to implement graph and trees using the STL in C++, so as to make it dynamic and to minimize memory leaks and segfaults.

One such implementation of adjacency list I found was by using an STL list<> inside a structure,

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    list<int> adj;
};
```

and then declare an array of struct pointers

```
struct Node *nodes[10005];
```

but all this is considering integer data, what if the data to be stored is not integer, how to use STL at its maximum potential?

Comment: *"so as to make it dynamic and to minimize memory leaks and segfaults"* ... *"then declare an array of struct pointers"*. If you're looking for dynamically sized and safe from segfaults, a statically sized raw array is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: `what if the data to be stored is not integer` - use templates. I don't know how you are going to code your data structure but a vector of nodes is probably better than a fixed array of arbitrary amount.

Answer (score 1):

use template classes
for example

```
template<class t1>
class node
{
 public:
    t1 value;
    node * link;
    void getdata(t1 val)
       {
        value=val;
       }
 };
```

now you can deal with any type of data

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on what will be done with such structures. Let's start with your second question - to use any type, apply templates

```
template<class T>
class Node
{
 public:
   T value;
   std::list<int> nodeIndices;
}

struct Node *nodes[10005];
```

If you wish to use different types in a single graph structure, combine above with inheritance

```
class BaseNode
{
 public:
   std::list<int> nodeIndices;
   // some functions  
};

template<class T>
class Node : public BaseNode
{
 public:
   T value;
}

struct BaseNode *nodes[10005];
```

This way you can store objects of different types. Another remark might be to use std::array instead of classic array.